# Dividing an array equally in C

Tags: c, linux, arrays, divide

i am writing a C in Linux, forks a parent and N children. the Parent takes the sqrt(ArraySize) and the rest is divided equally upon the N children.

how could i divide the rest of the array equally upon the N children?\

Thnx in advance :)

Comment: Do you have any example code you can give us? That way we can provide you an answer which is very relevant to you. Same variable names, etc.

Comment: Is the answer `(unsigned)(((double)ArraySize - sqrt(ArraySize)) / N)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int arraySize = 100; // You would get a count from the array here
int nChildren = 5; // This would be provided by you as a parameter to this function
int parentSize = sqrt(arraySize);
int remainder = arraySize - parentSize;
int nChildSize = (remainder / nChildren) + 1
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with situations where the remainder can't be divided equally among the other processes. Admittedly, the question simply assumes that it can!

Answer (score 1):

You're not really telling us enough to give a full answer

```
Decide size of share for each child, also determine what to do with any "remainder"

For each child 
    allocate an array sufficient to hold the required number of value
    populate the array
```

Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: Pretty much, but there's no need to allocate new arrays I think. Arrays in C are just pointers, so you can have a pointer that you use to advance along the portion of the array you are interested in. Or you can just use the original array as-is and restrict your attention to certain indices of it.

Comment: @Robin - yes, I should have mentioned that - spent so long in the Java world I'd forgotten the use of pointers.

Comment: @mingos - it was a serious answer, and one we could elaborate further. My point is that many problems seem too hard, but when you break them down into explicit smaller steps they become tractable. I'm trying to help the questioner deal with the next problem he hits not just this one.

Comment: Essentially, you asked for more input instead of providing a solution. Helpful as it might be (and I don't question this: breaking the problem into steps is indeed good for understanding the problem better), I still think it would fit more as a comment :).